# How do I integrate an iBook into my app?

Tags: ios, ibooks

As best as I can understand, iBooks are much just like interactive PDFs. What language are they saved in, and what would be a good solution if I want to display or use an iBook in my app, which is written in Objective-C?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a good guide that breaks down the basics of the iBooks concept and how they work and can be produced:

http://mattgemmell.com/2012/01/19/ibooks-author-for-authors/

As for the points you have raised:

- What language?

Well, the iBooks format is a zip-like archive of assets. There's no language there per se, but the iBooks Author Mac app assembles your project and associated files into the required format.

- Display an iBook in an iOS app

Not possible. You can display normal documents that iOS supports like PowerPoint, Word, PDFs etc through a `QLPreviewController` or `UIDocumentInteractionController` for example.

I'd definitely recommend downloading the free `iBooks Author` Mac app from the Mac App Store, linked below:

http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/ibooks-author/id490152466?mt=12

Answer (score 2):

iBooks are developed using [iBooks Author](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CHEQFjAA&url=http://www.apple.com/ibooks-author/&ei=mJ7DT6SSDsKO6gH3hZ3TCg&usg=AFQjCNHMCBMuFJ3esY_bXR2PfoFLBIhybw&sig2=tJyIwjlvohPlX4Nt2IVLZw), not Xcode. In addition, iBooks are for use with the [iBooks application](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGEQFjAA&url=http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibooks/id364709193?mt=8&ei=Cp_DT8z9OPCK6QG53dShCg&usg=AFQjCNGhCD5RdwV_Uk1gwETRN9AoCJZJNQ&sig2=zJFBozneVeHXjW9c1-Qi6Q) that is available for newer versions of iOS. They are not meant to be used within an iOS application.

Answer (score 0):

For the new iBooks 2.0 you can just use the [iBooks Author application](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibooks-author/id490152466?ls=1&mt=12).